# MySQL: Find lowest free number or append

Tags: mysql, sql

I am searching for a solution how to find the lowest number of a column between all data rows.

MY Table `"bot_instances"` has a column called `"bot_port"`.
I got a defined lowest port 9000 and may have ports open ended.

For example there might be data rows 9000, 9001, 9005, 9006 then the desired query should return 9002

Also it might be 9001, 9002, 9004 then the query should return 9000
Or maybe 9000, 9001, 9002 then the result should be 9003

I did not find a solution here. I only found one that replies on all numbers being present but a second field to mark the numbers as free.
For me the free numbers are missing in the table. There are only records for used ports.

I hope there is somebody out there able to help me out.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you simply want:

```
select (case when tt.min_port > 9000 then 9000
             else min(t.port) + 1
        end)
from t cross join
     (select min(port) as min_port from t) tt
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.port = t.port + 1);
```

Most of the outer query gets the first port that is missing.  The additional join for `min_port` is there to determine if the first value is missing.

Comment: Thanks that's a perfect answer

Answer (score 0):

You can also use variables to get the first available port:

```
SELECT MIN(bot_port) - port_diff + 1 AS available_port
FROM (
   SELECT bot_port,
          IF(@t := @p, IF(@p := bot_port, bot_port - @t, 0), 0) AS port_diff
   FROM bot_instances
   CROSS JOIN (SELECT @t :=0, @p := 8999) AS v
   ORDER BY bot_port) AS t
WHERE t.port_diff > 1
```

Given the following set of input data:

```
bot_port
--------
9000
9001
9002
9006
9007
```

the inner query returns:

```
 bot_port, port_diff
---------------------
 9000       1
 9001       1
 9002       1
 9006       4
 9007       1
```

The outer query gets `9006`, which is the first port after a gap of > 1, subtracts `port_diff` to get the previous port value, then adds `1` to get the next port, which is the first available port.

[**Demo here**](http://rextester.com/LPIIER84395)

Given the following set of input data:

```
bot_port
--------
9001
9002
9006
9007
```

the inner query returns:

```
bot_port, port_diff
-------------------
9001       2
9002       1
9006       4
9007       1
```

So, `9001 - 2 + 1 = 9000` is returned by the outer query for this marginal case.

Comment: Thanks also to you for this very well explained answer.